# Regular Expression For File Names In PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract some data from the defined pattern, which is as follows:

```
OCC_10020811_R08_2012_13_SYH
```

I have to extract 'R08' out of it. I need PHP regular expression for it.

Comment: `/.*_(R08)_.*/` there you go.

Comment: SO isn't a coding service. What have you tried?

Comment: Is that your only filename and you want just 'R08'? You don't need a regular expression for that.

Answer (score 3):

You dont really need a regular expression for that. Try:

```
 $pieces = explode('_', $string);
 echo $pieces[2];
```

Comment: Thanks this is also good idea for my requirement.